# Validation of password and changing its color according to password length:

Tags: javascript

I want to write a code with the help of that I can find the length of the code and according to that I can change the color of error. Like if the password is less than 4 then it would show in Red and if 8 than yellow and if 12 than green.

My initial code is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPasswordLength(password){
     if (password.length > 12) {
  document.getElementById("errorSpan").innerHTML = "Limit is 12characters";
     }
     else {
         document.getElementById("errorSpan").innerHTML = "";
     } 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="password" name="pwd"onchange='checkPasswordLength(this.value)'>
<span id="errorSpan" style="color:red;"></span>
</div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok. So what's your question? What's working or not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: There should be plenty of code snippets out there for getting the length of a string. And as for changing the color all you have to do is `document.getElementById("errorSpan").style.color = "#FDFF00";` for yellow and `document.getElementById("errorSpan").style.color = "#FF0000";` for red

Comment: [color hex](http://www.color-hex.com/color/000000)
[string length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)
[change element color](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
function checkPasswordLength(password) {
  var span = document.getElementById("errorSpan");
  if (password.length >= 12) {
    span.style.color = "green";
    return;
  } else if (password.length >= 4) {
    span.style.color = "yellow";
    return;
  } else {
    span.style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" name="pwd" onkeyup='checkPasswordLength(this.value)'>
<span id="errorSpan" style="color:red;">****</span>
```

You already had `document.getElementById`, so all you need to do is set the `.style.color` to whatever you need. If you need to change the text you can use `.innerHTML` as you were doing.

Note that I changed from `onchanged` to `onkeyup` because `onchanged` is only going to fire when the control loses focus.